# Join table with IdClass

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join

In my project, the following structure of entities.

```
public class FriendId {
    private String profileFrom;
    private String profileTo;
    ...
}
```

For Friend entity used as a PK - FriendId.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FRIEND")
@IdClass(FriendId.class)
public class Friend {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROFILE_UUID_1", nullable = false)
    private Profile profileFrom;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROFILE_UUID_2", nullable = false)
    private Profile profileTo;

    ...
}
```

The problem is that I cant do join in the method `findFriendsByUser`.

```
public List<User> findFriendsByUser(String userUuid) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> query = builder.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> userRoot = query.from(User.class);
    Join<User, Profile> profileJoin = userRoot.join(PROFILES);
    Join<Profile, Friend> friendsJoin = profileJoin.join(FRIENDS);
    Join<Friend, Profile> profileFriendsJoin = friendsJoin.join(PROFILE_TO);
    Join<Profile, User> userFriendsJoin = profileFriendsJoin.join(USER);
    Predicate userPredicate = builder.equal(userFriendsJoin.get(UUID), userUuid);
    query.select(userRoot).where(userPredicate);
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

I catch this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve attribute [profileTo] against path [null]
```

The only solution to use annotation @Embeddable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/IdClass.html

```
The names of the fields or properties in the primary key class and the primary key fields or properties of the entity must correspond and their types must be the same
```

That's not the case here, types are different !